# Google Chrome Local Storage Adding Links

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

So I'm trying to add an option on my options page for people to set 1-3 letters as a link to a website. Currently I'm getting a NaN value for the linkNumber when I run the function.

The Function:

```
function addLink () {
    chrome.storage.local.get('linkNumber', function (x) {
        if (x.linkNumber == undefined) {
            chrome.storage.local.set({'linkNumber': '0'}, function() {
                addLink();
            });
        } else {

        var linkNumberInteger = parseInt(x.linkNumber);

        var handle = document.getElementById("short");
        var link = document.getElementById("long");

        var handleValue = handle.value;
        var linkValue = link.value;

        var handleNumber = x.linkNumber + '-handle';
        var urlNumber = x.linkNumber + '-link';

        var objectOne = {};
        var objectTwo = {};

        objectOne[handleNumber] = x.linkNumber + '-handle';
        objectTwo[urlNumber] = x.linkNumber + '-link';
        console.log(x.linkNumber);
        console.log(handleNumber);

        chrome.storage.local.set({handleNumber: handleValue}, function(y) {
            console.log(y.handleNumber + ' handle saved');
        });

        chrome.storage.local.set({urlNumber: linkValue}, function(z) {
            console.log(z.handleNumber + ' link saved');
        });

        var linkNumberIntegerNext = linkNumberInteger++;
        var n = linkNumberIntegerNext.toString();

        chrome.storage.local.set({'linkNumber': n}, function() {
        });

        alert('Link Added');
        }
    });
}
```

The Html:

```
<h3 class="option">Add Quick Link:</h3>
    <input contenteditable="true" type="text" class="short-quicklink" id="short" maxlength="3">
    <span>http://</span><input contenteditable="true" type="text" class="long-quicklink" id="long">
    <button class="add">Add Quick Link</button>
```

Comment: As a side note: you don't need to serialize values for `chrome.storage`. You can just store a number directly.

Comment: 0.0 ohhhh my goodness I got it mixed up with the html5 local storage articles I read, my bad, let me go make some changes haha

Comment: @Xan on a side note, how in the world are you always online

Comment: I'm not; but I often monitor [tag:google-chrome-extension] and [tag:google-chrome-app] for updates, so I react relatively quickly.